# Input Redirection in C - Using fgets to read from stdin not working

Tags: c, io, stdin, fgets

I have an assignment where I need to create a shell in C. One of the specifications is to implement input redirection when the redirection symbol is entered ('<'). Then I am attempting to read the input from `stdin` using `fgets`. After the input is read, the `saved_stdin` is restored to the normal input stream.

However, on the first time the input is redirected, it works perfectly. Then, on the times after that, nothing is read from `stdin`. I have tried debugging several times but cannot find my error. Would really appreciate your help!

My code is below so that you can be able to reproduce the error, and help me correct my mistakes. Also, make sure to create a file named `text.txt` in the directory where you're running the program. Contents of `text.txt`:

```
hello, how are you?
```

*Note that the code is extremely simplified and I am simply using hard-coded arguments. In my actual implementation, input is being given by the user (I am 100% sure that there is nothing wrong with receiving the input).*

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ARG_LENGTH 100

int redir_in(char **args, int in_pos);
void echo();
void reset();

// Global Variables
int saved_stdin;
bool changed_in;

int main(void)
{
    // sample arguments (args)
    char *args[MAX_ARG_LENGTH] = {"echo", "<", "text.txt"};
    // position of '<'
    int pos = 1;

    printf("output 1: ");
    if(redir_in(args, pos) == 0){
        echo();
        reset();
    }


    printf("\noutput 2: ");
    if(redir_in(args, pos) == 0){
        echo();
        reset();
    }

    printf("\nexiting...\n");

    return 0;
}

void echo()
{
    char line[MAX_ARG_LENGTH];

    while(fgets(line, MAX_ARG_LENGTH, stdin) != NULL)
        printf("%s", line);
}

// args is an array of inputted string arguments, in_pos is the index 
// of '<' in the array
int redir_in(char **args, int in_pos)
{
    char *file_name;
    file_name = args[in_pos + 1];

    int fd;
    fd = open(file_name, O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR);

    if (fd < 0)
        return -1;

    saved_stdin = dup(0);

    dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd);

    changed_in = true;

    return 0;
}

void reset()
{
    if(changed_in){
        dup2(saved_stdin, 0);
        close(saved_stdin);
        changed_in = false;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
output 1: hello, how are you?
output 2: hello, how are you?
exiting...
```

Output I'm getting:

```
output 1: hello, how are you?
output 2: 
exiting...
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about how we can reproduce the problem. Show the input (contents of `text.txt`) you use, the actual and expected output and if necessary describe why the actual output is wrong.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, I get the expected output. See https://onlinegdb.com/DVz2ZNk0Q

Comment: You are right, it is working there. However, in VSCode, where I am using my linux terminal basically, it is not. Do you have an idea of why this may be?

Comment: Did you test exactly the code from the question? I don't know why it might behave differently. I'm not sure, but I think in `reset()` you should `close(STDIN_FILENO)` before `dup2(saved_stdin, STDIN_FILENO);`. Apart from this I suggest to check all return values for error indications. And functions with no arguments should be written as `void echo(void);` etc. (C is not C++)

Comment: Not a solution but just a note: In your final shell product, when a redirection is done, the stdin could correspond to a pipe which cannot be reset and read again. Once rad, a pipe will not be readable again. Of course currently you have been assigned for the "<" operator, but the next assignment will probably be the "|" operator...

Comment: @ fpiette thanks for the concern, I implemented piping already using fork and file descriptors so that's done and it works fine :)
@ n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m it does not work on the standard linux terminal either, that is why I'm so confused.

Comment: When you pass the arguments to your program, are you properly escaping the `<` in the command line? Because if you don't, it gets interpreted by your command shell instead of getting passed to your program.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to your question, please read upto the end of this answer, as there are more things that I had to comment about your code.

First, you mix constant identifiers and the values themselves in the code, just to confound your readers?

```
    saved_stdin = dup(0);

    dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
```

or you write:

```
    saved_stdin = dup(STDIN_FILENO);

    dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
```

or

```
    saved_stdin = dup(0);

    dup2(fd, 0);
```

Please, be uniform and coherent.

Second, if you use `S_IFRUSR`, then you need to include `<sys/stat.h>`, which you don't.

Also, if you declare `main()` as `int main(void)`, please do the same with `void echo(void)` and `void reset(void)` as `void echo()` and `void reset()` means that the compiler should allow you to pass `echo()` an undefined list of parameters (legacy syntax for variable argument passing), and it will not detect possible errors in case you change the interface.

The redirection code should be ok, except for minor things like not checking `dup()` and `dup2()` return values.  In my system (FreeBSD 13.0) `stdin` renounces to give you more input once it has flagged `EOF`, (this happens also now to linux) so to be able to continue reading from it (remember that stdio is a library, not a set of system calls like `open()` or `close()`), you should call to `clearerr(stdin);` once you have detected EOF in `stdin` in function `echo()`:

```
void echo(void)
{
    char line[MAX_ARG_LENGTH];

    while(fgets(line, MAX_ARG_LENGTH, stdin) != NULL)
        printf("%s", line);
        clearerr(stdin);   /* <--- this call allows you to read again after EOF */
}
```

This is the reason for `stdin` not to read anything else after redirecting back.  I included a call to `echo();` in between the two `if` statements, to check that the redirection worked back to the `saved_stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two distinct APIs here -- the *Unix* API working on `int` file descriptors (`open`, `dup`, `dup2`, `close`, with `0` for standard input) and the C standard API working on `FILE *` handles (`fgets`, with `stdin` for standard input).

This is generally a bad idea. It is *possible* to make them work with each other, but it is fragile, and (needlessly) platform-dependent.

You can redirect `stdin` using the standard API as well, which I would recommend on general terms. Use `fopen`, [`freopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen) (for attaching a file to `stdin`), `fgets`, and `fclose`.

Answer (score -1):

`stdio` and redirection do not mix. You dup your file descriptors but stdio looks at `FILE*` which has no idea about these manipulations. Once `stdin` is at `feof`, it is at `feof`.

Use `read` instead of `fgets` (don't forget to null-terminate the resulting buffer, remember that it is not a string). Alternatively, you can try to set stdin buffering mode to `_IONBF` and/or call `clearerr` each time you `dup` corresponding `fd`, but I have not tried that.

Comment: That's not true. **stdio** mix perfectly with redirection. You have to be careful to flush buffers before redirecting, but they mix perfectly. See my answer.

Comment: @LuisColorado You cannot flush an input buffer.

Comment: Yes, you can.  flushing an iinput buffer just deletes all the characters buffered in the input buffer, making next read to read again from the input file descriptor.  But to flush the input buffer, you have to call `fpurge()`.

Comment: @LuisColorado The C standard says flushing an input buffer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have not mention `fflush()`  I've said about flushing buffers, which is done with `fflush()` for output buffers, and with `fpurge()` for input buffers.  Please, read my comments, and don't think I'm talking only about `fflush()`.

Comment: @LuisColorado `fpurge` is not a standard C function. The manual page says *These  functions are nonstandard and not portable.  The function fpurge() was introduced in 4.4BSD and is not available under Linux. The function __fpurge() was introduced in Solaris, and is present in glibc 2.1.95 and later. NOTES Usually it is a mistake to want to discard input buffers.*.

Comment: Nobody has talked about the ANSI-C standard but you. I don't mind how do you flush the input bufffers (if calling setbuf(NULL); and then back or whatever... The problem here is not about buffering, but about calling `clearerror()` which is the actual problem.  You have already been downvoted (not by me, by the way) because you are supposing that stdio cannot be mixed with redirection.  I don't mind `fpurge` not being ansi-c.  I've not used it in the solution I proposed.  I have given a full and complete answer to the question.  Bye.